# He fed me a line about how he was late because his car broke down

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

It is an example of 'feed (someone) a line' in [the Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feed%20%28someone%29%20a%20line#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20tell%20(someone)%20a,because%20his%20car%20broke%20down.).

How about rewriting the example as '**He fed me a line about how he was late that his car broke down**'?

Is the rewritten sentence ungrammatical or does it have a different meaning?

Comment: You sentence as it is, is wrong. There is no context in which it is correct.

Comment: Thank you. How about this? 'He fed me a line about why he was late that his car broke down.'

Comment: Similarly. You could have 'He fed me a line about why he was late'.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Peter There is nothing wrong with the original sentence in the title, as one would not expect there to be. It does after all, appear in Webster's dictionary. But the replacement would also be correct if it was correctly punctuated. ***He fed me a line about how he was late; that his car broke down***. A semi-colon is needed after "late".

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @WS2 You are right. I missed that possibility.